# Unable To Initialize 5th Generation ipod Touch on GTKpod or Rythmbox

Tags: ipod, music-player

Running UBUNTU 14.04 LTS

Cant add music to brand new ipod touch 5th gen 16 GB

Is ipod touch model "ME643LL/A" not supported by either GTKpod or Rythmbox?

When i run gtk ipod manager a message immediately pops up saying "iPod directory structure not found"  so i click  "create directory structure", then it asks for my model, which isnt present in the list.

When i run rhythmbox it immediately asks if id like to initialize my ipod but the model drop down menu is greyed out and nothing happens when i click the initialize button

i think my inability to initialize with these apps is stopping me from adding music to my device.

Answer (score 0):

It should be supported out of the box on Ubuntu 14.04LTS, but for earlier versions of Ubuntu, you may want to read this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone

Comment: Perhaps you should add a little more information to your question?

Comment: i added more info with my question idk what else may help